# WP-CLI: detect altered core files and restore them automatically

Tags: wp-cli, core, automatic-updates

I know that there is a command to verify the integrity of the core files:

```
$ wp core verify-checksums
```

In case a file is corrupted or altered, is there any WP-CLI command to automatically restore all those files? E.g. download those files from the official repository and restore.

This could be a useful command to run every 24 hours for example, together with any updates, in order to keep the Wordpress installation intact and safe.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall the current version of WordPress Core with:

```
wp core download --force
```

For a bash script, you could modify this one from https://dannyvankooten.com/periodically-check-wp-core-file-modifications/. You would need to make it run the download command, rather than send a notification.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /my/wp/directory

if [ -e /tmp/wp-core-verify-checksums-notified ]; then
        exit
fi

if [ ! $(wp core verify-checksums) ]; then
        curl https://api.pushbullet.com/api/pushes \
              -u MY_API_KEY: \
              -d type=note \
              -d title="WP checksum verification failed." \
              -d body="Checksum of your WP core files does not match the checksum of original core files. What up with that?" \
              -X POST

        touch /tmp/wp-core-verify-checksums-notified
fi
```